# Show that $|p'(x_0) - f'(x_0)| \le C\|f^{(3)}\|_{\infty}h^2 $

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

Let $x_k,  y_k \in \Bbb R, \ x_k = kh, \ k = 0, 1, 2$ and $h \in (0,1)$. For a polynomial $p \in P_2$ (of degree $2$), I already calculated

$$p'(x_0) = {{4y_1 - 3y_0 - y_2} \over 2h}$$

Now, let $f \in C^3(\Bbb R)$ such that $f(x_k) = y_k$.

I want to show that

$$|p'(x_0) - f'(x_0)| \le C\|f^{(3)}\|_{\infty}h^2 $$

for a constant $C > 0$.

I guess it would be wise to use the Taylor formula here, so for example, we'd get

$$y_0 = f(x_0)$$

$$y_1 = f(x_1) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)h + {{f''(x_0)} \over 2} h^2 + {{f'''(\xi_1)} \over 3} h^3.$$

Now, I believe that I have to use this formula to calculate $f'(x_0)$. Is this the correct approach? And what would I have to do next then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You know](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lagrange_Polynomial_Approximation) that for a quadratic interpolation polynomial you get the interpolation error
$$
p(x)-f(x)=-\frac{f'''(\xi_x)}{6}(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)
$$
so that
$$
\frac{p(x)-p(x_0)}{x-x_0}-\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=-\frac{f'''(\xi_x)}{6}(x-x_1)(x-x_2)
$$
Now take the limit $x\to x_0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But where would I use the derivative of the polynomial that I calculated before?

Comment: The left side converges to $p'(x_0)-f'(x_0)$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to write $p'(x_0) - f'(x_0) =  \ ...$ directly then?

Comment: Try it and use no more than 5 lines of equations. It is not easy to get this coefficient of the error term, i.e., $C=\frac16$. If you can get by with larger coefficients, you can combine Taylor formulas.

Comment: Thanks! We found a method for now, though we calculated $C = 1/3$, not $C = 1/6$.

Comment: Sorry, yes, $C=\frac13$ is optimal as $(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ tends towards $2h^2$ for $x\to x_0$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! :-)